# Spring batch - Job remains blocked on the status STARDED

Tags: spring, database, spring-batch, query-optimization, postgresql-9.2

I have a job with a single chunk step executed in parallel (8 partitions) :

- Reader : JdbcCursorItemReader
- Processor : use jdbcTemplate to call database (1 thread for each partition)
- Writer : write in file

I use a JdbcCursorItemReader to read millions of data from shared Postgres Database (v9.2).(other users use database at the same time)

Spring batch version : 3.0.6

**The problem is the job and steps are blocked on status STARTED after some hour of execution with any errors in log**

Before blocked :
[image]

After blocked

**the table pg_stat_activity is empty (i think processor are killed) and status job = STARTED**

[image]

[image]

Anyone have any idea why the job and parallel steps are blocked in STARTED status ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please share your job/step configuration code to be able to help you. If your job is killed abruptly, Spring Batch will not have a chance to update the job status correctly in the job repository. Hence it will be stuck at `STARTED`. This is explained in the docs here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/job.html#aborting-a-job

Comment: My problem is why the job is blocked because i have a some problem when i start a new execution after some hour. is problem job configuration? reader? or Postgres kill transactions

Comment: Before talking about restarting your job and how to do that, we need to understand why it is blocked in that status. Is your job still running and blocked in the STARTED state? was it killed in the middle of processing?

Answer (score 0):

Job configuration
[image]

[image]

My problem is why the job is blocked on status STARTED because i have a some problem when i start a new execution

Comment: This is not an answer to your question. Don't add an answer with more details about your question. You can edit the question and add details.